# haproxy ssl_fc_sni not matching correctly

Tags: haproxy

I am a bit lost with my HAproxy configuration. Currently running 1.6.4. We have a system in place that determines the backends using the SNI valused provided by the client.

This has been working well in the past, however today I've added a `use_backend` rule to the following frontend and it does not work as intended:

```
frontend fe_ssl
        description "SSL Endpoint"
        bind 1.2.3.4:443 ssl crt /etc/haproxy/certs/

        tcp-request inspect-delay 5s
        tcp-request content accept if { req_ssl_hello_type 1 }

        use_backend bk_t1 { ssl_fc_sni -i subdomain.domain.com }
        use_backend bk_t2 { ssl_fc_sni -i subdomain-test.domain.com }
```

Previously only backend bk_t1 was presend and it did work like intended: If accessing `subdomain.domain.com` the traffic was forwarded to bk_t1, if using any other name pointing to the same IP it resulted in a HTTP 503 as there was no matching backend.

Now after adding bk_t2 it does not *ever* match requests to the backend that is mentioned second in the frontend configuration. Meaning:

- If `bk_t1` is defined first all requests will be routed to `bk_t1`, no matter if accessing `subdomain.domain.com` or `subdomain-test.domain.com`
- If `bk_t2` is defined first all requests will be routed to `bk_t2`, no matter if accessing `subdomain.domain.com` or `subdomain-test.domain.com`

I am thinking that it could have something to do with the fact that the two subdomains are partly identical but I was not able to find any information that "-" needs to be escaped and even switching from `-i` to `-m str` or putting the hostnames in quotes does not change anything

Answer (score 2):

After troubleshooting for two hours and writing this entry I realized that my mistake was very obvious. The `if` was missing for the statements to match.

```
use_backend bk_t1 **if** { ssl_fc_sni -i subdomain.domain.com }
use_backend bk_t2 **if** { ssl_fc_sni -i subdomain-test.domain.com }
```